# error loading page when clicking return button in angular browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, components

All the components are loaded correctly but when entering another and returning the page is not shown active, I have a primeng carousel, and a navbar which when returning from another component are not shown active but when starting they are shown.
app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'',component:HomeComponent},
  {path:'federacion',component:AcercaFederacionComponent},
  {path:'desarrollador',component:AcercaDesarrolladorComponent},
  {path:'perfilDocente',component:AcercaDocentesComponent},
  {path:'proyectos',component:ProyectosComponent},
  {path:'eventos',component:EventosComponent},
  {path:'laboratorios',component:LaboratoriosComponent},
  {path:'lab360/:id',component:Lab360Component},
  {path:'contactanos',component:ContactanosComponent},
  {path:'crudUsuarios',component:CrudUsuariosComponent},
  {path:'crear-usuario',component:CrearUsuarioComponent},
  {path:'login',component:LoginComponent},
  {path:'error',component:Error404Component},

  {path:'editar-usuario/:correo2',component:CrearUsuarioComponent},
  {
    path: 'panel-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: PanelEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'perfil-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: PerfilEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'publicaciones-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: PublicacionesEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: 'chat-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ChatEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'bolsa-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: BolsaEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'calendario-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: CalendarioEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'reservas-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ReservasEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'aplicaciones-estudiante',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: AplicacionesEstudianteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  
  {
    path: 'reserva-laboratorios',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ReservaLaboratoriosComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'reserva-equipos',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ReservaEquiposComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'estudiante'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'panel-docente',
    component: PanelDocenteComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'docente'
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'panel-administrador',
    component: PanelAdministradorComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    data:{
      role: 'administrador'
    }
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

This is my app-routing.module.ts

Comment: Bro we need your code where return date is.

Comment: sorry is return button of the browser, all te buttons with the tag active don't found :(